# Can you change a whole running C# Project with SQL Server from simple BLOB to FileStream and use both them?

Tags: c#, sql-server, blob, filestream

I have a C# WPF Project in my company where simple BLOBS are strored in the SQL Server Database.
I have to mention that before most of the cases the BLOBS haven´t reached the 1 MB.
Now there is a new Window in developement where customers can report different things and additionally take a picture and add it. I think that alomst every picture taken with a smartphone is bigger then 1 MB.
So for this case itself it is clear, that using FileStream would be the best choice.
Now I have the problem to choose it is possbile or not to switch the whole project over to FileStream. But therefor I have to find out if it is possible to switch everything that was just BLOB in the past to FileStream or not. Because the whole project has to be in one way or the other. I think it is not the best approach because you should use what is best for every case but it has to be the same thing for everything.
 Maybe there is someone out there who had at least the problem to change everything from BLOB to FileStream and can give a recap of that work and most important if it is even possbile because the BLOBS are directly saved in the database file and everything wrote with FileStream is not.

**EDIT:** If it is a running SQL Server right now with nother BLOB Fields already existing, do I have to change all the other fields then to FileStream or can I Insert in one Table normal BLOBS and in the other table with FileStream? Does the Database handle that itself like "Ok normal BLOB insert then save it there and FileStream insert then save it there" or when I activate FileStream for the DB have I always to use FileStream?

Comment: Please add code reference, how blob is currently being accessed in C# code.

Comment: Have you considered to reduce image dimensions and quality before storing into the database? I'm pretty sure you would get good enough quality with 1Mb image. If you follow this approach you would not need to change anything.

Comment: Max size of data is 2,147,483,647 bytes.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You should consider not storing images and documents inside the database itself. Although FILESTREAMs are stored outside the database they are managed by the SQL Server engine and are included in database backups and restores. Over time your database backups will grow considerably and time taken to backup and restore will grow, making it more difficult to meet RPO and RTO. One alternative is storing files and images in external repositories, such as S3 or Azure, and just store the references to them in the database.

Comment: Yes I know, In my last Stand-Up-Meeting I made a clear approach to push for my point of view and now it will be solved with FileStream. I considered all the other options including reducing the image size or most important storing the data in an external repsitory. But at the end of the day it has then to be in the MS SQL Database hoping that the amount of files would not explode in the future.